# How to remove a text fragment from the file using bat/cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have a html file and need to remove the text fragment between tags "t193270" and "t226481". It looks like:

```
    <a href="#" class="bt-home">В начало</a>
    </div><a name=183586> </a><div class="cont" id="193270">
    <h1 id="t193270" class="heading1">Управление программой</h1>
    ...
     ...
    <a href="#" class="bt-home">В начало</a>
    </div><a name=226360> </a><div class="cont" id="198854">
    <h1 id="t226481" class="heading1">Создание резервной копии и восстановление программы</h1>
```

I use the following batch script:

```
@echo off
set "f=all-in-one.htm"
set "tag1=t193270"
set "tag2=t226481"
for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ('findstr/rn /c:"^%tag1%$" "%f%"') do set/a nd=%%a
for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ('findstr/rn /c:"^%tag2%$" "%f%"') do set/a kd=%%a
<"%f%" (for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('"for /l %%a in (%nd%,1,%kd%) do @find /n /v ""|find "[%%a]""') do @echo:%%a)
pause>nul
```

It returns however the same unchanged file. Would you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best advice I can offer is that you do not use batch file scripting to attempt to make inline changes to a document, especially one which uses characters which are considered poisonous to the cmd.exe parser. PowerShell or Windows Scripting Host _(VBScript/JScript)_, are both built-in to the same Operating System, can modify a file contents without having to recreate the file as a new document, before overwriting the original, do not struggle with particular characters, and are better suited to Unicode character sets, as opposed to plain ANSI text with hard CR/LF line endings.

Comment: So you are getting the line number for the beginning and ending but why are you **NOT** using an `IF` condition to say IF the line number is **LEQ** to beginning number or **GEQ** to ending number then output.  That seems like the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Would probably help if you read the help file for the `FINDSTR` command. Open up a command prompt and type: `FINDSTR /?` and read the usage for `^` and `$`. As it stands the findstr code will never match an entire line.

Comment: You are also using the wrong delimiter for the `FOR` commands.  `FINDSTR` outputs a colon to show the corresponding line number. The `FIND` command outputs square brackets.

Comment: The last line of code is not removing everything between the two tags.  The code is finding all lines from the beginning tag to the ending tag.  Maybe it is a language barrier issue but you said you wanted to remove the text between the two tags.  You are printing every line from the beginning tag to the ending tag.  This is why I asked in my first comment why you are not comparing the line numbers with an `IF` comparison.

Comment: Regardless here is the fix for the `FOR` commands that get the line numbers. `for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /rnc:"\<%tag1%\>" "%f%"') do set "nd=%%a"`. Now you just need to change the last line of code to exclude the lines between the two line numbers it finds.

Answer (score 0):

So based on all my comments above about your code you could do something like this.

```
@echo off
set "f=all-in-one.htm"
set "tag1=t193270"
set "tag2=t226481"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /rnc:"\<%tag1%\>" "%f%"') do set "nd=%%a"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /rnc:"\<%tag2%\>" "%f%"') do set "kd=%%a"

FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%G IN ('find /N /V "" ^<"%f%"') DO (
    IF %%G LEQ %nd% echo %%H
    IF %%G GEQ %kd% echo %%H
)
```

This will output the following based on the example input file you provded.

```
<a href="#" class="bt-home">В начало</a>
</div><a name=183586> </a><div class="cont" id="193270">
<h1 id="t193270" class="heading1">Управление программой</h1>
<h1 id="t226481" class="heading1">Создание резервной копии и восстановление программы</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will consider PowerShell in the future. Now I needed a batch file, because it is the easiest format to integrate with the CMS system used in our company.
I tried your code and it works. However there is one problem - the text before %nd% is not displayed. Just for test I tried to output '''IF %%G LEQ %kd% echo %%H''' - it returns also the only string (the value of %kd%) and no text before it. So it seams the problem is in this operator. Maybe you have some ideas how to fix it. I would really appreciate your help, cause I'm a newby in batch scripts.

Comment: I don't understand why you would change the code like that. I fixed all your coding errors and you even said the code works. Then you said the text before nd is not displayed but the output I presented clearly shows the lines before the first tag based on the example input you provided. Then you decided to change the tag2 code to try and fix it. Clearly there must be a language barrier on what you want as output from this script.